# select li from hidden ul in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select a list item that has been hidden, but can be shown with the slide toggle method.

Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li id="par1">parent 1</li>
    <ul id="par1list">
      <li>items to select1</li>
      <li>items to select2</li>
      <li>items to select3</li>
    </ul>
  <li id="par2">parent 2</li>
    <ul id="par2list">
      <li>items to select1</li>
      <li>items to select2</li>
      <li>items to select3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

In the jquery, I'm hiding the sub parent lists (par1list and par2list), but they slide toggle when parent 1 or parent 2 are clicked.  here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#par1list, #par2list").hide(); //hide elements

    $("#par1").click(function() {
        $("#par1list").slideToggle(400); //click parents to show hidden elements
    });
    $("#par2").click(function() {
        $("#par2list").slideToggle(400); //click parents to show hidden elements
    });

    $("#par1list > li").click(function(){  //select list item from previous hidden ul
        this.css('color', 'red');
    });
});
```

I'm trying to select a list item from the ul par1, but I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: i saw the answer of Vega, so deleted my comment. I was trying to figure out what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood correctly you need to use `$(this)` instead of `this`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/9JeCu/)

```
$("#par1list > li").click(function(){  //select list item from previous hidden ul
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Wow.  that's it.  Thanks.  I knew it had to be something simple.  appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

I know this one already has a good answer, but I'd like to add the explanation of why it works that way:
"this" is a DOM element. like "hello", so in order to work with it using jQuery you first need to wrap it in a jQuery object, doing $(this).

Hope this was helpful.